# Can anyone recommend a method to perform the following string operation using C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, lexer

Suppose I have a string:

"my event happened in New York on Broadway in 1976"

I have many such strings, but the locations and dates vary. For example:

"my event happened in Boston on 2nd Street in 1998"
"my event happened in Ann Arbor on Washtenaw in 1968"

so the general form is:
"my event happened in X on Y in Z"

I would like to parse the string to extract X, Y and Z

I could use Split and use the sentinel words "in", "on" to delimit the token I want but this seems clunky. But using a full parser/lexer like grammatica seems heavyweight.

Recommendations would be gratefully accepted.

Is there a "simple" parser lexer for C#?

Comment: How do you intend to handle `my event happened in 1988 in boston on 2nd ave` or `my event happened in Houston on 1960 in 1960` (because 1960 is a very popular road in Houston TX)

Comment: @drachenstern: He states the pattern is "my event happened in X on Y in Z". It doesn't matter what `X`, `Y` and `Z` are; as long as the sentence fits this pattern then can be extracted.

Comment: No @Jason, he said "the general pattern is" not "the exact form is"

Comment: @drachenstern: I'm pretty sure my interpretation is correct, but I'm willing to be corrected. If I say the general form is `a^n + b^n = c^n`, I do mean exactly that. "General form" means the form to which all cases apply.

Comment: @Jason ~ Maybe I can reach your cortex via another method: User Input. He can't guarantee what the case will ALWAYS be, but he can predict what the most common will be. I'm trying to determine if he's thought that far ahead or if he's looking for one strategy that he will apply permutations on or what. I am of the opinion that the advice you give below is the strongest of the available choices. However, for a scraper (which he could also be doing) he needs to consider other options.

Comment: @drachenstern: He didn't say any of those considerations applied. He said "the general from is...." So reading what is given, and not reading between the lines, the most reasonable interpretation is the form is as given. He didn't at any point say this problem is fuzzy. He stated he is looked for a simple parser, which indicates to me that he has a rigorous "grammar" for the sentences that he needs to parse.

Comment: Hence I only asked "how do you intend to handle" and provided two edge cases. I didn't offer them as part of an answer to handle the generic cases. I also didn't ask how he intends to handle "my event occurred in on in 1960".

Comment: Let me clarify....I am reasonably sure the form I am trying to parse is always "my event happened in X on Y in Z". I am looking for a lightweight way of parsing this sort of statement.

Comment: @Andrew so just use the solution @Jason suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using regex pattern matching. Here's an MSDN link that should be pretty helpful:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308252

---

An example might help. Note that a regex solution gives you scope to accept more variants as and when you see them. I reject the idea that RegEx is overkill, by the way. I'm no expert but it's so easy to do stuff like this I do wonder why it's not used more frequently.

```
var regEx = new Regex(
        "(?<intro>.+) in (?<city>.+) on (?<locality>.+) in (?<eventDate>.+)"
        );

var match = regEx.Match("My event happens in Baltimore on Main Street in 1876.");

if (!match.Success) return;
foreach (var group in new[] {"intro", "city", "locality", "eventDate"})
{
    Console.WriteLine(group + ":" + match.Groups[group]);
}
```

Finally, if performance is a real worry (though ignore this if it isn't), look [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Compiling_Regular_Expressions) for optimisation tips.

Comment: @Andrew it's a famous quote on the internet about http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html ... it's sort of a tongue in cheek expression "this is not a case for using regex"

Answer (score 4):

KISS applies here. Just do the `String.Split` solution, or use `String.IndexOf` to find the "in" and "out" (frankly, `String.Split` is the simplest). You don't need anything more complicated for such a simple "grammar"; note in particular that regex is overkill here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but what put me off this approach were examples such as "my event happened in Boston on Arlingt on in 1998". So the typing error of inserting a space in Arlington has introduced an "on" token. This would confuse the split.

Comment: Uhh...it confuses any approach that expects correctly formatted input. You said parse, not validate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the string is always going to be in that format then you can do as you have already figured out by splitting by words **"in"** and then by **"on"**.

To be sure you would like to then search for the Found words in a **Database** of City  names and Year for **Validity of search**.

---

If string may not be in that format always  then you can do is Search for the whole string for Words and match them against database of City names and Years and check them for Validity.